# on image hover display div over image

Tags: javascript, css

What I'm trying to achieve is on hover over the image, display the hover div over the image; I created this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcdued0s/1/) but I don't exactly know how to achieve what I'm trying to do.

```css
    .hover {
       background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-image-128.png");
       height:75px;
       width:75px;
          background-size: contain;
          opacity:0.7;
          }
```

```html
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QQzdPIF.jpg" height="75px" width="75px"/>
    
    <div class="hover"></div>
```

Comment: Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/kcdued0s/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="img">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/QQzdPIF.jpg" height="75px" width="75px"/>
<div id="hover"></div>
</div>

.img:hover #hover{
  display:block;
}

    #hover {
                background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-image-128.png");
                height:75px;
                width:75px;
          background-size: contain;
          opacity:0.7;
          position:absolute;
          left:0;
          top:0;
          display:none;
    }
```

Working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/kcdued0s/3/

Comment: Thankyou; thats exactly what I was after, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 .hover:hover {
     opacity:1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap it in a containing div(`hoverwrap`) that's relatively positioned.
It just needs the attribute, so the child element that are positioned absolute will take that as an anchor instead of the document.

Then set your width parameter on the wrapper, and have the child elements width 100% so it will always fill up the size of the wrapper.

Then have the image hide by default, and only show on hover.(done with the `display:none` value and `display:inline-block`

```css
.hover {
  background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-image-128.png");
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.hoverwrap {
  position: relative;
}
.hoverwrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.hoverwrap .hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.hoverwrap:hover .hover {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverwrap" style="width:75px;height:75px">

  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QQzdPIF.jpg" />

  <div class="hover"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS

```
<div>
   <img ... />
   <div class="hover"></div>
</div>

.hover{
   ...
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}
img:hover .hover {
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute for hover image

```
.hover {
      background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-image-128.png");
      height:75px;
      width:75px;
      background-size: contain;       
      opacity:0.7;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top : 0;
      left: 0;
}
  img:hover ~ .hover {
  display:block;
}
```